# If then for href URL to load different templates in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I need an If then statement that will load a different template in opencart `product.tpl` file depending on the URL

If URL = `domain.com/product1` or `product_id` use

```
<?php require( PAVO_THEME_DIR."/template/product/product_detail_product1.tpl" );  ?>
```

else

```
<?php require( PAVO_THEME_DIR."/template/product/product_detail_default.tpl" );  ?>
```

Comment: Can you describe your question with more description? So that we can understand what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
    <?php if ($product_id == 135) { ?>
    <?php require( PAVO_THEME_DIR."/template/product/product_detail_product1.tpl" );  ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php require( PAVO_THEME_DIR."/template/product/product_detail_default.tpl" );  ?>
<?php } ?>
```